# 2 way Switch powerbar

Tags: power

For some important reasons the plugged cable 1 must not be on at the same time as the the plugged cable 2. It must be idiot proof...

I'm talking about regular house power north america.

What is the specific name of it. I've done some research and I can't find anything. I thinking about crafting the thing with 2 powerbar and a custom button, but I'm looking for something less homemade.

Thanks

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with robotics. You should post it here: http://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or [electronics.se]

Comment: I can't tell if you are talking about an interlock, where only one cable can be plugged in at a time, or a "DPDT break-before-make" relay or switch, where both cables are plugged in and you toggle power from one cable to the other. Either way, off-the-shelf solutions already exist. Either have a one-outlet junction box, or, like I said, use a (properly rated) DPDT relay or switch. Use a relay if you want to operate it remotely or a switch if you're willing to manually toggle it.

Answer (score 1):

The idiot proof solution is not to have two cables.

Comment: ??? How ? A single cable will be wrong in all cases, and more than 2 is nonsense...

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**.

Comment: @Mark "*A single cable will be wrong in all cases*" how so? From how I understand your question, there should never be both cables plugged in.

Comment: @Mark Booth♦shouldn't this question be migrated?

Comment: I don't migrate questions which would be closed on the target site @BendingUnit22 It's not realy suitable for DIY and I know what Electrical Engineering is like, it would be closed in an instant there.